# MySQL does not start in XAMPP 1.7.3 for Windows

Tags: mysql, xampp

In 2000 I had installed XAMPP 1.7.3  on my Windows 7 64 Bit machine in **F:/xampp**. I always started the XAMPP Control Panel Application  from this folder, clicked on the "Start" buttons for the MySQL and the Apache so it looked like this:

https://docs.moodle.org/19/de/images_de/e/e6/29_Apache_Stop-de.png

I recently decided to install the XAMPP 5.6.3 version to **F:/xampp2**. I imported another database and working on this new database was fine.

However, for some reason I cannot start the MySQL server in the **F:/xampp** any more. The Apache server does start. But when I click on the "Start" button in the XAMPP Control Center the text "Running" flashes up in green for a second (see linked picture above) and vanishes again. Nothing happens. In (this version 2.5.8 of) the Control Panel no additonal info is displayed in the log.

I tried everything to avoid a duplicate posting:

1. The other Mysql server in **F:/xampp2** not running. The Port Check function of the Control Panel says 3306 is free.
2. Skype is not running.
3. There is no mysqld.exe in the Windows Task Manager
4. Checked services.msc - there is nothing running related to MySQL.
5. I ran netstat in a command line and there was no sign of 3306 anywhere.
6. I changed 3306 to 3307 in the f:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini. Nothing!

There are many threads like this one and I tried everything except to "delete and reinstall". I cannot delete **F:/xampp** - I have 500 GB and 500 tables of data in the **F:/xampp** MySQL database that my life depends on. I do not even want to touch the data in there and risk any loss.  I cannot delete  **F:/xampp2** either. What can I do?

Thanks!

EDIT: I tried the following in the commandline:

```
   f:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
   150602 6:03:24 [Warning] Can't create test file \usr\local\mysql\data\MY-PC.lower-test
   150602 6:03:24 [Warning] Can't create test file \usr\local\mysql\data\MY-PC.lower-test
   f:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Can't change dir to '\usr\local\\mysql\data\' (Errcode: 2)
   150602 6:03:24 [ERROR] Aborting
   150602 6:03:24 [Note] f:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

EDIT 2: I looked for the mysql.err file in f:\xampp\mysql\data.

```
    150602  7:04:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    InnoDB: Error: log file \xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
    InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 1073741824 bytes!
    150602  7:04:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
    150602  7:04:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
    150602  7:04:01 [ERROR] F:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown variable 'innodb_file_format=barracuda'
    150602  7:04:01 [ERROR] Aborting
    150602  7:04:01 [Note] F:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

**EDIT 3: Thanks for your comment, I tried the following but it there are other errors:**

```
    f:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql --help
```

gives me inter alia:

```
    Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
    C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf f:\xampp\mysql\my.ini f:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf
```

then i try this line and I know that the my.ini file is there:

```
    f:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-extra-file=F:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
    150602 14:39:21 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '\xampp\mysql\share\english\errmsg.sys'
    150602 14:39:21 [Warning] Can't create test file \xampp\mysql\data\MY-PC.lower-test
    150602 14:39:21 [Warning] Can't create test file \xampp\mysql\data\MY-PC.lower-test
    f:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Can't change dir to '\xampp\mysql\data\' (Errcode: 2)
    150602 14:39:21 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Go to `F:\xampp2\logs` or alike, there must be a logfile somewhere and it should tell you the exact error. It might also appear in the `Windows Event Log`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found errors in the mysql.err file, see my edit. However, I do not know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt - press `Win key + R` and type in `cmd`.

In the command prompt type in `F:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe` and press `Enter`. (note it is `mysqld` with a `d` in the end)

What do you see? There should be an error, possibly regarding your config file.

**EDIT**:

Try using:
`F:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-extra-file=F:\path\to\config`

Comment: Thanks, the result is as follows:

Comment: So there is no result - meaning the command prompt just stays open with an empty new line? Try connecting to the mysql server, but do not close the command prompt window - you should be able to connect.

Comment: no sorry for this misunderstanding, I inserted the output in the EDIT of my original post above. I could not put it into this small comment section.

Comment: OK, it looks like mysqld is not reading the proper ini file, try the same command in the prompt but append:  --defaults-extra-file=F:\path\to\config

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggested. The result is in EDIT 3

Comment: Sorry for giving this info piece by piece - could you try the same command but this time - from an elevated command prompt (run `cmd` as administrator), and also - change to `F:` before running the command (you need to type in `F:` and hit enter in the prompt before invoking).

Comment: Thanks, the result was now different. I navigated to F:\xampp\mysql\bin> then I entered the command --defaults-extra-file=F:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini and then nothing happened, only F:\xampp\mysql\bin>  was displayed.

Comment: Once this happens - try opening phpmyadmin, if nothing happens, this usually means mySQL should be now running (provided the prompt stays blank, and does not present you with a new row).

Comment: unfortuntaly it does not work (PhyAdmin says: #2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) ). I also can call the code mysqld --defaults-extra-file=F:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini  several times and nothing happens

Comment: by the way: after executing the code in the command line, I can see the green text "Running" in the Xampp control panel for a second. Then it vanishes again.